# Onsubmit html + javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма, на ней висит `onsumbit="return func1"`. В `func1` у меня проверка полей, если поля заполнены - `return true`, если нет - `false`. Когда возвращается true, то `action` происходит и формочка кидает сервлету запрос, а если нет - появляется `alert`. Но если после алерта я введу верные данные, то `submit` всё равно не происходит. Появляется `alert`- и всё.

В чём может быть дело?

```
//script

<script type="text/javascript">
function ehehe() {
            if(document.getElementById("creditCardOwner").getAttribute("value").length > 0 &&
                document.getElementById("creditCardNumber").getAttribute("value").length > 0){
                alert("good");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                alert("bad");
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>

//body
        <form id="creditCardForm" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return ehehe()">
            <div id="creditCardArea">
                <p id="bankCartaText">БАНКОВСКАЯ КАРТА</p>
                <input type="button" id="changeForCreditCard" onmouseenter="return pointerChange1()"
                       onmousedown="edit1()" value="Ред.">
                <p id="ImyaText">Имя владельца банковской карты</p>
                <span id="lalala1"><input id="creditCardOwner" name="creditCardOwner" type="text"
                                          minlength="5" maxlength="25" onfocus="return deleteText1()"></span>
                <p id="nomerBankCart">Номер банковской карты</p>
                <span id="lalala"><input id="creditCardNumber" maxlength="16" name="creditCardNumber"
                                         onfocus="return deleteText()"
                                         onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></span>
                <input id="CVV" minlength="3" maxlength="3"
                       onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
                       pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="Three letters CVV code">
                <input type="submit" id="submitChangesButton1" value="сохранить">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: код обычно говорит лучше чем слова описывающие код)

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Описание, каким бы хорошим оно ни было, хуже, чем пример.